# JavaScript Sort Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm wanting to sort an array of arrays based on a array and then by length of items in the array.

Take the following master sort array:

```
const key = [
  "meraki",
  "gsuite",
  "active directory",
  "sophos",
  "manageengine"
]
```

I want to take a array that resembles:

```
const raw = [
  ["manageengine"],
  ["sophos"],
  ["active directory"],
  ["gsuite"],
  ["meraki"],
  ["sophos", "manageengine"],
  ["active directory", "sophos"],
  ["active directory", "manageengine"],
  ["gsuite", "active directory"],
  ["gsuite", "sophos"],
  ["gsuite", "manageengine"],
  ["meraki", "gsuite"],
  ["meraki", "active directory"],
  ["meraki", "sophos"],
  ["meraki", "manageengine"],
  ["active directory", "sophos", "manageengine"],
  ["gsuite", "active directory", "sophos"],
  ["gsuite", "active directory", "manageengine"],
  ["gsuite", "sophos", "manageengine"],
  ["meraki", "gsuite", "active directory"],
  ["meraki", "gsuite", "sophos"],
  ["meraki", "active directory", "sophos"],
  ["meraki", "gsuite", "manageengine"],
  ["meraki", "active directory", "manageengine"],
  ["meraki", "sophos", "manageengine"],
  ["gsuite", "active directory", "sophos", "manageengine"],
  ["meraki", "gsuite", "active directory", "sophos"],
  ["meraki", "gsuite", "active directory", "manageengine"],
  ["meraki", "gsuite", "sophos", "manageengine"],
  ["meraki", "active directory", "sophos", "manageengine"],
  ["meraki", "gsuite", "active directory", "sophos", "manageengine"]
];
```

In the above example, I want the `raw` array to be sorted by accordingly to each item in the `key` array. My first attempt was to do something like:

```
const result = [];
for (const name of result) {
  const sorted = keys.filter((s) => s[0] === name);
  result.push(...sorted);
}

result.sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
```

However that only takes into account the first item in the array, not the sort of the rest of the items.

Comment: Is the key constant, or does it change with some kind of input or expected code changes?

Comment: I think you want `for (const name of raw)`, then, in that loop, `const sorted = name.sort((a,b) => keys.indexOf(a) - keys.indexOf(b))`. You'll likely need some kind of recursive sort for the outer array, since it needs to sort by length, then by the contents of each array.

Comment: Firstly, your "result" contains different items from the "raw" array - the third line, `["sophos", "active directory"]` seems to have become `["meraki", "active directory"]`.  Is that just a typo?  Secondly, your requirement was to sort by **key then length** but your output is by **length then key** - which is it?  Should all those starting with "meraki" appear first and sorted by length, or should all those with just one entry appear first, sorted by key?

Comment: @ATD - Good catch - i updated the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort you have to first check the length. If both are equal we have to check the index positions of the first element of `a`/`b` within `key`. If those are the same move on to the next element in both arrays.

This answer makes use of the fact that `0` is a falsey value. Examples are: `0 || -1 //=> -1` and `1 || -1 //=> 1`

```js
const key = ["meraki", "active directory", "sophos"];

const raw = [
  ["meraki"],
  ["active directory"],
  ["sophos", "active directory"],
  ["active directory", "sophos"],
  ["sophos"],
  ["meraki", "active directory", "sophos"],
];

raw.sort((a, b) => (
  a.length - b.length || a.reduce((diff, _, i) => (
    diff || key.indexOf(a[i]) - key.indexOf(b[i])
  ), 0)
));

console.log(raw);
console.table(raw); // check browser console
```

Comment: Another option would be `a.reduce((diff, a, i) => diff || key.indexOf(a) - key.indexOf(b[i]), 0)` instead of `upto(a.length).reduce(...)` but I despise the asymmetry in that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```js
const key = [
  "meraki",
  "active directory",
  "sophos"
]
const raw = [
   ["sophos"],
   ["meraki"],
   ["active directory"],
   ["sophos", "active directory"],
   ["active directory", "sophos"],
   ["meraki", "active directory", "sophos"]
]

const compareThis = (a, b) => {
  if (a.length !== b.length) {
    return a.length - b.length
  }
  let itemFound = 0;
  for (let keyIndex in key) {
    for (let aIndex in a ) {
      if(a[aIndex] === key[keyIndex]) {
        itemFound = -1;
        break;
      }
      if(b[aIndex] === key[keyIndex]) {
        itemFound = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(itemFound !== 0) { break }
  }
  return itemFound;
}

const sortedData = raw.sort(compareThis)

console.log(sortedData)
```

Comment: Side note: you are missing the 'var' in the 'for' loops

Comment: I think its inverted now.

Comment: Could you share a wider array for debugging?